# error in passing parameter

Tags: postgresql, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard jdbi, and database postgresql:

```
@Mapper(StudentMapper.class)
  @SqlQuery("select user_registration.username,user_registration.user_email,user_registration.picname,"
            +"student_specific.subject_name from user_registration inner join "
            +"student_specific on user_registration.user_email=student_specific"
            +".student_email where (subject_name @> ARRAY[':subject'])"
            )
  StudentDetails searchStudents(@Bind("subject")String subject);
```

my problem is when i give ARRAY['maths'] it will give result, but when i give ARRAY[':subject'] it returns me null, seems it is not binding subject and taking ':subject' as value please help me out how to pass :subject

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator**, this annotation allows us to use the `<arg>` syntax in the queries.
Example:

```
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
public interface StudentDao {

      @Mapper(StudentMapper.class)
      @SqlQuery("select user_registration.username,user_registration.user_email,user_registration.picname,"
                +"student_specific.subject_name from user_registration inner join "
                +"student_specific on user_registration.user_email=student_specific"
                +".student_email where (subject_name @> ARRAY[<subject>])"
                )
      StudentDetails searchStudents(@BindIn("subject") List<String> subject);
}
```

You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
ARRAY[<subject>]::text[]
```

and escape `::`

```
ARRAY[<subject>]\\:\\:text[]
```

To use StringTemplate add this dependency to `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```